# icalendar Event in QR Code

Tags: icalendar

I am generating a QR Code in InDesign to include in flyers, so that interested people can quickly scan the code and add the event to their calendar. The idea is if they can be reminded of the event, we get more people in the door.

So far, everything is working great...except: I don't know how to format the icalendar event such that I receive RSVP responses from people who scan the code. If the event had to change for whatever reason, I'd like to be able to email the people who scanned it. As I have it structured now, when I test scan the QR code my email address receives an *invitation* and not the expected RSVP response saying the scanner is attending. I have read the specifications for icalendar, but have come away just as confused because the specs are surprisingly short and thin.

Current ical event:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
SUMMARY:Event Title
LOCATION:Venue Name\, Venue Address
DESCRIPTION:Event description
DTSTART:20171115T180000
DTEND:20171115T190000
URL:http://webaddress.org
ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:myemail@address.org
BEGIN:VALARM
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:-PT120M
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:Reminder
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
```

It's the `ATTENDEE` line that I can't figure out. The spec makes it sound like that would cause the person responding to automatically send an acceptance to the email address that follows, which is mine as the event organizer. That's not what happens, so is there a different component to use to get what I desire?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is an application concern, not anything to do with the iCalendar spec. I'll drive through your ical text quickly, though:

- Your RSVP request is formatted fine.
- You don't need the `URL` line.
- You need [`VERSION:2.0`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.7.4). Some applications (like Apple's Calendar app) can't parse ical text without it.
- You [need a `PRODID`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.7.3).
- Depending on the location(s) of your attendees relative to the venue, it might make sense to specify a `TZID`, or (since it's not a recurring event) express your start and end time in UTC.

In general, you should use an iCalendar library like ical.net or ical4j to build your calendar events. They'll keep you from 1) needing to know the spec, which probably isn't a good use of your time and 2) shooting yourself in the foot because of #1.

> The spec makes it sound like that would cause the person responding to automatically send an acceptance to the email address that follows, which is mine as the event organizer.

This is magical thinking: how would that happen? It would have to be handled by an application or operating system. Something that would "know how" to 1) understand ical, and 2) send a web request or an email or do something else.

The spec [allows the organizer to indicate a preference with respect to RSVPs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.17), that's all:

> **Purpose:** To specify whether there is an expectation of a favor of a reply from the calendar user specified by the property value.

It's up to the implementer of the software to determine what that *means* in the application layer: send a web request, send an email, ignore it, etc.

Presumably scanning the QR code does something. How is the ical text loaded? How should it be loaded? By the user's mobile mail client? By the mobile calendar application? Something else? You need to figure out what THAT action should be, and figure out how to trigger or handle it.

Comment: I do need the URL line, as that shows up in the event as a web address for the person to get more info.

In my testing, iOS has handled this ical event just fine without the version or PRODID, but I will add it for other devices' compatibility.

I'm not sure you even read my post as you responded to things I didn't ask for and ignored the fact that I had tested the ical text in a QR code successfully. Scanning the code in iOS gives the option to add the calendar event. Adding the event causes the device to send an email automatically, but I receive an invitation not an affirmative RSVP.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the RFC suggests that a possibly better interpretation of this line:

ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:myemail@address.org

is that you have added a single attendee, that attendee's email address is myemail@address.org, and that attendee is required to RSVP.

As a result, when you add this calendar event to your calendar, the calendar evaluates it and says: "Wait, we haven't even *invited* myemail@address.org." and then does so.

I actually wouldn't have expected that behavior, and would tend to see it as a bug (side-effect behavior that the user would have no reason to suspect, and which would potentially leak information (like their email address)).

It may help to think of this as you specifying the calendar entry as it will appear on their calendar, as if they created it.  As such, they aren't an attendee, they are the organizer.

I think you need to specify a METHOD:REQUEST line per the RFC: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.7.2 and IETF draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-calsify-2446bis-09#section-3.2.2

This should change the entry from a static representation of an entry in your calendar to an invitation.  You will probably need a few more things per the IETF doc (like a UID).